# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type (struct node)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, dereference, avl-tree

I am writing a simple AVL tree implementation using C. I am having issues with my code at various parts of. Sometimes I get this error, sometimes dereferencing works quite well.

Here is how my *struct node* looks:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    int height;
};
```

Here is where I get the dereferencing error (exactly on **if (data < (p->data))**)

```
struct node* search(struct node* p, int data)
{
    if (!p)
        return NULL;
    if (data < (p->data))
        return search(p -> left, data);
    else if ( data > p -> data )
        return search(p -> right, data);
    else
        return p;
}
```

Also here:

```
struct Node remove_min(struct Node *x)
{
 if (x->left == NULL)
     return x->right;
 x->left = deleteMin(x->left);
 return x;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are the `struct Node` definition and the code where you are seeing this error in the same file?  If not, can you be more explicit about how your code is organized, what your `#include` statements look like,  etc?  Ideally you can provide a simple reproducer that will completely demonstrate the problem.

Comment: where is your code , when you are calling search , i mean your codes of the main?

Comment: I have posted whole my code as an answer, you can have a look at it there, thanks.

Comment: `struct Node {....} node;` declares a *variable* called `node` of type `struct Node`. There is no `struct node`, thus your error.

Answer (score 2):

Change `struct node` to `struct Node`.